# which jar to use for JSTL

Tags: java, jsp

(server Tomcat7v)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
First Name:<c:out value="${param.fname}"></c:out><br/>
Last Name:<c:out value="${param.lname}"></c:out>
```

in the previous JSP and I am getting

```
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

this error.
But when I try to find out the jars there were lots of version of that I am confused with which one should I use??

Comment: can any one please help lots of my work got stuck because of this.I am not able to move further.

Comment: I'm using el-api2.2.jar and el-impl2.2.jar, and there may be a later version.

Comment: we can use JSP EL and JSP Action Tags to write JSP code like HTML but their functionality is very limited. For example, we can’t loop through a collection using EL or action elements.

JSP Standard Tag Library (JSTL) is the standard tag library that provides tags to control the JSP page behavior, iteration and control statements, internationalization tags, and SQL tags. 

JSTL is part of the Java EE API and included in most servlet containers. But to use JSTL in our JSP pages, **we need to download the JSTL jars for your servlet container**.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put **jstl jar** in your classpath. See details at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: I've dropped 1.0.5 JSTL jars still getting the same error. am I going with the right version of jars?? @Mr. Oronno

Comment: @PiyushMittal The info page explains which jar(s) you need depending on which version of the servlet/JSP API you use. Read it *carefully*.

Comment: it was my bad, I were using Tomcat 7v which uses servlet 3.0 so I had to use jstl1.2.1 jars @JB Nizet

Comment: He needs to put *which version*? That's the question being asked. The StackOverflow tag you cite is not a normative reference, and in this case it is many years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I were using Tomcat 7v which uses servlet 3.0 so I had to use jstl1.2.1 jars